# Including jpgs into Beamer when using sharelatex or writelatex

Tags: beamer, graphics, sharelatex

I'm trying to include a `jpg` into `Beamer`. Many of the sources I've looked at mention that it's necessary to include the `graphicx` package in the preamble, and to use something like `\includegraphics{myimage.jpg}`. I've done these, and have made sure the name of my file exactly matches the name I use in `\includegraphics`. I got the error that my file was not found, but I've located it. I've tried specifying where it is by using  `\graphicspath{c:/Users/Me/Desktop/}` in the preamble, but that hasn't worked. Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Put the file or a copy of the file in the folder the `.tex` is located.  Also you only need `\includegraphics{myfile}` no `.jpg` needed.  Also, you don't need to load the `graphicx` package in the `beamer` class.

Comment: Thanks @dustin. What about if I'm using sharelatex? Isn't the .tex file stored online then?

Comment: I just looked at `writeLaTeX` and they say you need to upload the file and then `\includegraphcis[]` so my guess is `shareLaTeX` is the same.  I have never used those services.